# what changes should i make to this model to achieve higher precision accuracy

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am using a keras convolutional 2d neural network to solve a classification issue, however the best accuracy i can achieve is around 30%. what should i do to achieve higher precision accuracy with this model?

this is the code im using to create the model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3,3), input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(20, activation='softmax'))
adam = Adam(lr=3e-4)
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

the x data contains 2480 races, 20 runners for each race, and 100 variables for each runner having a total shape of (2480, 20, 100)
the y data represents the winner of each race and is one hot encoded, 2480 races, with 20 y labels for each race. having a total shape of (2480, 20)

this dataset can be found [here](https://gofile.io/d/8xjwiy) and loaded into memory using the following code:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.loadtxt("x_data").reshape(2480, 20, 100)
y = np.loadtxt("y_data").reshape(2480, 20)
```

all this data is float variables stored in plain text data.
x is 100 * 20 * 2480 variables
y is 20 * 2480 variables

first value in y looks like

```
[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
```

this represents runner number one winning the race

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what exactly does your y data represent? It's not a bad idea to include a snippet of your data in the post itself. Few people will bother downloading your data from external source.

Comment: y data represents the winner of the race only it is a one-hot encoded array, i have edited the question to hopefully make it clearer

Comment: First of all, I'd use a sigmoid activation since you essentially have a binary classification problem.

Comment: thank you for your reply, do you mean replacing the softmax? or the relu activations i have used? it seems the network doesnt learn when i use sigmoid instead of any of these.. val_accuracy doesnt increase at all

Comment: I again suggest you read [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/12/31/keras-conv2d-and-convolutional-layers/) and choose the best parameters for your layers. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the reply, again suggests you once did already but thanks this is more helpful than the last. but it seems your telling me I am doing something wrong but not what..

Comment: You are asking a broad question. To answer your question, one needs to understand(EDA) your data, then preprocess if required, then do transformations/feature engineering if required, then assume the architecture of the neural network and do hyper tuning. Finally finds what works best for you. So, I *again suggest you* do all this and come with a specific problem. So, the SO community can help you more precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First things first - For numerical data, don't use a Convolutional Layer at all.**

Just use 3 to 4 Dense Layers with proper regularization layers like BatchNorm and Dropout for a goof fit. And also you need to use softmax as your y(target) is one-hot encoded. Use the default Adam learning rate, that should be good enough.

Categorical Crossentropy + Softmax = Multi-class Classification 
Binary Crossentropy + Sigmoid = Multi-Label Classification

Referring on the 100 variables, the batch shape would be (None, 2800, 100). 2800 refers to the no. of data points (Rows), 100 refers to the features per sample (Columns) & None refers to the batch size. You need to reshape it as (2800, 100)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is alot of help i was using dense layers only to begin with and the accuracy was not so great but that may have been to do with the data shape you have mentioned, i will definitely take your advise on board

Comment: Worked perfectly! doubled the accuracy already thank you for that..

Comment: @ZacBurns Glad that it helped you! Use regularization to prevent over fitting and to increase the test accuracy. I also have a Tensorflow-Tutorials on my GitHub, I will leave the link in this comment. Feel free to refer it anytime. I will be updating it mostly every week from this weekend. [TensorFlow-Tutorials](https://github.com/pranavraikote/Tensorflow-Tutorials)